# Rewrite rule to redirect all subpages to a single page?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have two two files `/etc/apache2/sites-available/foo` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/foo_maintenance`

The rewrite rule I use in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/foo` is

```
<Directory /var/www/public_html>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteOptions inherit
        RewriteEngine on
        #
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</Directory>
```

so that all `mysite.com/*` redirect to `www.mysite.com`

After I take my site down for maintenance, if the user is navigates to a subpage of the site like mysite.com/subdir/something.php I would like to redirect them to www.mysite.com so the index.html of the maintenance page would be displayed.

What is the rewrite rule to redirect all traffic from any subpage to `www.mysite.com`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

RewriteRules have three parts. A pattern to match, the replacement, and the flags. The pattern in this case is `^(.*)$`. The `^` represents the beginning of the line, and the `$` represents the end of the line. The `.` represents any character, and the `*` following it means that it can occur any number of times. Now, the round brackets define a capture group, which essentially stores everything that occurs between the brackets. These capture groups are then available for you to use in the replacement. So if the request is for `/subdir/something.php`, then the first capture group will contain "/subdir/something.php".

The replacement in this case is `http://www.mysite.com/$1`, and the `$1` represents the first capture group in the matching pattern. The target URL is formed by filling in these capture groups, which in this case will yield `http://www.mysite.com/subdir/something.php`.

So if you want to always send users to the root of `www.mysite.com` regardless of the path which they requested, you just need to not fill in the path in the replacement, i.e. by removing the `$1` part. Your final rule will look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I'm getting a redirection loop error.  btw what are u doing up this late if youre in mountain view?

Comment: @user784637 Did you replace your existing RewriteRule with this one (i.e. retaining that RewriteCond)? I wish I knew the answer to that question... ;-)

Comment: Yah =( Unfortunately it's not redirecting, it loads the subpages.  I started with the directive I included in the original post, then the only I change I made was removing the `$1` part

Comment: Hey Michael - Sorry, I wasn't fully clearing the browser cache, your solution works

Answer (score 5):

You can go with something along the lines of this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mysite.com/ [L]
```

- Line 1 enables the rewrite engine in this context.
- Line 2 checks if the request is sent to *mysite.com*.
- Line 3 checks if the requested URI is not already */*.
- Line 4 redirects all addresses to *http://www.mysite.com/*.

Comment: This isn't redirecting subpages to the homepage, it just loads the subpage

Comment: I fixed a typo in the 3rd rule (slash doesn't have to be escaped), maybe that was the problem. Other than that, I don't see why it wouldn't work. Do you have any other rewrite rules in the virtual host that we should be aware of?